# Use environment variable in YAML with Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, environment-variables, yaml

I am working in a Spring Boot project with Gradle and an application.yml with the properties.

How can I declare the property logging.config in a YML file to config Logback using an environment variable?

`logging:
  config: ${PATH}/application-log.xml`

This way, the build fails in the :processResources task. I understand, Gradle tries to replace ${...}

I have tried changing to ${'PATH'} but I got the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder ''PATH'' in string value "${'PATH'}/application-log.xml"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI : this works perfectly fine in maven.

Comment: Do you have `expand()` configured on the `processResources` task? Otherwise I don't understand why it's treating the `${}` as anything special. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files for more info on filtering content during a copy.